# Android reference styles

Tags: android, android-theme

In Android, can I reference a big chunk of properties?

This is what I have right now:

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/CheckBox</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Button</item>
    <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/ImageButton</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/Spinner</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItem</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyleHorizontal">@style/ProgressBar</item>
    <!-- More items not shown-->
</style>
 <style name="CompatTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">

    <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/CheckBox</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Button</item>
    <item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/ImageButton</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/Spinner</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItem</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyleHorizontal">@style/ProgressBar</item>
    <!-- More items not shown-->
</style>
```

As you can see, the DialogTheme and CompatTheme have exact same items.
I thought copying all the items from DialogTheme to CompatTheme was not future proof(there are more styles that require the same item properties).

Is there a way where I can pull out all the properties and later reuse them together somewhere else?